# trying to populate a template with ngfor where the first 2 elements should be exposed as a row,

Tags: html, css, angular, for-loop

I´m trying to commit this task where through a ngFor iterating an array i must to display the first 2 elements of that array in a row, then the other elements in a descending column. Kind of:

```
first  second

third

fourth

fifth

..nth
```

for that i iterate over the array and trying to apply ngclass to condition the first two elements i set this:

```
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                      <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
                        <span [ngClass]="{ 'd-flex flex-column': i > 1 }">
                          <div>{{item}}</div>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

But that´s not clearly working cause all the elements are displayed in row still. Any comment about how can i improve this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the issue is your css

Comment: could you explain

Comment: Please share your css code

Comment: no css code...all is in template  with boostrap css classes

Comment: all from flex classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SPAN or DIV *flex* CSS styled container that aligns content within the same row requires any content to be wrapped within it's own DIV.

In the code below I have removed the *d-flex* CSS class in the first line and the *flex-column* CSS class from the SPAN to keep the div content onto the same line for the first two items.

Before you can place the first two elements in a flex within the same container element, you will need their values beforehand. Alternatively, store the first two values in the first element of a list within your component code and read them as the first item of your array and output on each row.

Try this:

```
<div class="flex-row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i = index">
        <span *ngIf="i==0">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div>{{myArray[0]}}</div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>{{myArray[1]}}</div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i==1">
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="i>1">
            {{item}}
        </span>
</div>
```

The above will give you the desired output.